# Javascript appendChild(script) works only one time

Tags: javascript, text, window, edit, appendchild

I'm trying to create two separate HTML documents: **main.html** and **sufler.html**. Idea is to control **sufler.html** page from **main.html** . So far I succeeded to write text and change it's font style. But font style changes only **ONE time**...

I need it to be able to change **many** times, can't understand what is going on,
because, as I understanding, every time I calling function `writing()`, I'm clearing all new document's content with `newDoc.body.innerHTML = ''`... but it seems that not... although text is changing every time.

**main.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var HTMLstringPage1     = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link href="stilius.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>',
    HTMLstringPage2     = '</body></html>',
    HTMLstringDiv1      = '<div id="sufler"><div id="mov"><p id="flip">',
    HTMLstringDiv2      = '</p></div></div>';

//NEW WINDOW OPEN--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var newWindow   = window.open('suffler.html','_blank','toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, height=615,width=815'); 
var newDoc      = newWindow.document;
                  newDoc.write(HTMLstringPage1,HTMLstringDiv1+'Text'+HTMLstringDiv2,HTMLstringPage2);
var script      = newDoc.createElement("script");
                  script.type = "text/javascript";
//=======================================================================================================================

//WRITING----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function writing(){
    newText =   document.getElementById("sel-1").value.replace(/\n/gi, "</br>");
    fontas=     document.getElementById("textFont").value;
    size=       document.getElementById("textSyze").value;
    stylas=     document.getElementById("textStyle").value;
    syntax=     document.getElementById("textSyntax").value;

    newDoc.body.innerHTML = '';//clears old text (should clear old scripts and functions too)
    newDoc.write(HTMLstringPage1,HTMLstringDiv1,newText,HTMLstringDiv2,HTMLstringPage2);//writes new text (and new scripts and functions)
    
var text        = newDoc.createTextNode('document.getElementById("flip").style.font="'+stylas+' '+syntax+' '+size+'px '+fontas+'";');
    script.appendChild(text);
    newDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
}
//=======================================================================================================================
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" style="background-color: #F5FF25;" onclick="writing()">Apply     text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any one node can only be added to the document once. You only define `script` once but trying to add it to the DOM multiple times. Put the `var script = ...` line inside `writing()`.